# Add attribute in Savon request

Tags: ruby, xml, attributes, savon

How can I add the attribute 'updateVersion' in the request, when using the following format:

```
response = client.call( 
  :method, :message => { extID => 'X-1234', ..., '@updateVersion' => '0' }
)
```

I need to set the updateVersion to `0` for my call to be successful and of course the `extID`.

When using response = `client.call( :method, xml: "xml")` then it is working as expected, but I'd like to see/test the other option.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:int="http://www.url">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <int:policyInList>
         <!--0 to 1000 repetitions:-->
         <int:policyID main="true" system_id="0" updateVersion="?">
            <extID>X-1234</extID>
         </int:policyID>
      </int:policyInList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking but have you tried `client.call( :method, message: { extID: 'X-1234', attributes!: {'int:policyID': { 'updateVersion': 0 }})`? I cannot guarantee this works since I have never tried to modify the attributes of something that was not contained in the "message" itself

Comment: Thanks, but it is unfortunately not working. I'm getting the error message: Error parsing Element [interfaces-root:policyInList: null] in Document [#document: null];
I'm asking how to set an attribute in a request when it is outside the message. In above example I need to set the updateVersion to '0',